# Modal window not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page I have two modal windows. They are opened when user clicks buttons on the page. But I also want to be able to open second window when user clicks specific button on the first modal. 
Here my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.details-btn').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Device/Details",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("wystąpił nieokreślony błąd " + data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.modal-body').html(data);
            $("#DetailsModal").modal('show');
            $(".DeviceEdit-btn").on('click', function () {
                $('#DetailsModal').modal('hide');
                $("edit-btn").trigger('click');
            });
        }
    });
});
$('.edit-btn').on('click', function () {
    console.log("triggered");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Device/Edit",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("wystąpił nieokreślony błąd " + data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.modal-body').html(data);
            $("#EditModal").modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

});

as you can in `.details-btn` click event I hide a modal( this works) and trigger click on the button which should show second modal. But second modal doesn't show up.
How modify this code to make this work.
Is a problem connected with this that `edit-btn` on click event is declared after `details-btn` where trigger is?

Comment: You're missing the dot from the selector $("edit-btn")

Comment: Just to note... nested modals are pretty bad user experience. If possible you should only have one modal showing on the page at a time. You could link between the two instead.

Comment: @Alex Yeah thats why I'm closing first modal before opening other. @ heymega Thanks. Damn Js why its not showing this as error :D Put it as anwer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are Not placing the dot

```
 $("edit-btn").trigger('click');
```

change with

```
  $(".edit-btn").trigger('click');
```